# Random Array Values are null

Tags: java, arrays, null

Here is my situation: I have an array `answerChoices[][]` and I am creating 2 new arrays based off of the values in `answerChoices[][]`. The first one `finalAnswerChoices1[][]` is created as:

`System.arraycopy(answerChoices, 0, finalAnswerChoices1, 0, finalAnswerChoices1.length);` and the behavior is as expected. However, for my second array I only need specific elements from `answerChoices[][]` and I create the final array like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < widebodies.length; x++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
          finalAnswerChoices2[x][y] = answerChoices[widebodies[x]][y];
           }
     }
```

and `widebodies` is an array of integers.

My issue is this: when the second method is used to create `finalAnswerChoices2[][]` some of the values inside are null. The biggest issue is that I cannot repeat it 100% of the time because to me it appears "random" which value are null and if any are null. Some cases there are no null values, and other cases there are "random" null values. The first method of using `arraycopy` does not cause any issues.

Any suggestions for what could cause this odd behavior?

Comment: You said you only needed specific elements from `answerChoices[][]`, that means the new array wont have all the elements and if their size is the same you'll have some null values.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I meant was say for example it is `answerChoices[row][column]`, I will only require specific rows and all of the columns for that row in the new array. And my experience is that an entire row is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your `finalAnswerChoices2.length` differs (is larger) from `widebodies.length` or `finalAnswerChoices2[0].length` differs from `6`. Therefore the `finalAnswerChoices2` array will contain still the `0` values (default) from the array initialization, at those positions your loop won't reach.

Comment: Thanks, with your comments I was able to find my error. Now it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, if `ansquerChoices[][]` is 2x3 (for example) and `widebodies[]` have, for example, the Integer 10, when try to acess `answerChoices[10][y]`, would be an exception... but instead it returns `null`.
I hope this helps you with the problem, greetings.

Comment: This is not the case, the values attempted to accessed are never outside the length of `answerChoices[][]`